# Most specific generic function not called

Tags: swift, generics, swift5

I'm using `@propertyWrapper` to reduce my `UserDefaults` boilerplate as follows…

```
enum PreferenceKey: String, CaseIterable {
    case enumName, stringName
}

@propertyWrapper
struct Prefs<T> {
    let key: PreferenceKey

    var wrappedValue: T? {
        get {
            UserDefaults.object(for: key)
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.set(newValue, for: key)
        }
    }
}

struct Preferences {
    @Prefs(key: .enumName) static var enumName: Name?
    @Prefs(key: .stringName) static var stringName: String?
}

extension UserDefaults {

    static func object<T>(for key: PreferenceKey) -> T? {
        standard.object(forKey: key.rawValue) as? T
    }

    static func object<T: RawRepresentable>(for key: PreferenceKey) -> T? where T.RawValue == String {
        if let value = standard.object(forKey: key.rawValue) as? String {
            return T(rawValue: value)
        }
        return nil
    }

    static func set<T: RawRepresentable>(_ value: T, for key: PreferenceKey) {
        print("Set Raw Value \(value)")
        standard.set(value.rawValue, forKey: key.rawValue)
    }
    static func set<T>(_ value: T, for key: PreferenceKey) {
        print("Set Value \(value)")
        standard.set(value, forKey: key.rawValue)
    }

}
```

This works fine when setting a regular property list type…

```
Preferences.stringName = "Fred"
// Set Value Optional("Fred")

print(Preferences.stringName)
// Optional("Fred")
```

But when trying to set a value that is `RawRepresentable`, it fails…

```
Preferences.enumName = .Fred

// Set Value Optional(__lldb_expr_10.Name.Fred)
// libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Rather than calling the most specific version of `UserDefaults.set(`, it calls the non-specific one.

Just calling

```
UserDefaults.set(Name.Fred, for: .enumName)
```

works fine. In this case it calls the most specific function.

---

With further testing, and it seems that this isn't a `@propertyWrapper` issue. The following top level function also fails to call the more specific generic function. It seems like some type information is being lost somewhere

```
func set<T>(_ value: T?) {
    UserDefaults.set(value, for: .enumName)
}

set(Name.Fred)
// Set Value Optional(__lldb_expr_5.Name.Fred)
// libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

*What am I missing? Any thoughts as to how I can resolve this?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *What am I missing?*

Swift is essentially a statically typed language and selecting which of your function overloads to call is determined at compile time.

In your working example:

> ```
> UserDefaults.set(Name.Fred, for: .enumName)
> ```

the type of the first argument is known by the compiler. This type implements `RawRepresentable` and the compiler uses that to select the overload you expect.

Now consider your failing example:

> ```
> func set<T>(_ value: T?) {
>    UserDefaults.set(value, for: .enumName)
> }
>
> set(Name.Fred)
> ```

When the compiler compiles the `set` *function* the only thing it knows about the argument `value` is that is has a type which it can reference as `T`. There are no constraints on `T`, at runtime a value of *any* type can be passed, so in determining which overload of `UserDefaults.set` to compile a call to the compiler can only select the overload which also has no constraints and accepts a value of any type.

> *Any thoughts as to how I can resolve this?*

You already know one solution, you overloaded `UserDefaults.set`, you could overload your `set` function. However you might wish to consider your design here in the light of Swift's compile-time resolution of overloads – you may not want layers of overloaded functions calling each other.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give such a detailed response.